# Iteration over a ListStore in Java Gxt

Tags: java, debugging, compiler-errors, iterator, gxt

So I am working with grid widgets in java...and when trying to iterate over the ListStore I get the following error.

```
[javac]   required: array or java.lang.Iterable
[javac]   found:    ListStore<String>
```

Any tips for how I would solve this/ create an iterator for this?

Here is my code:

```
public void cycle(ListStore<String> line_data){

    for(LineObject line: line_data){
          //Other code goes here
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: @rozkosz Fixed to show code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the javadoc shows [List Store](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3/com/sencha/gxt/data/shared/ListStore.html) does not implement [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).  So you cannot iterate over it using a for each loop.

Just use the [getAll()](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3/com/sencha/gxt/data/shared/ListStore.html#getAll()) method of List Store which returns you a [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) which properly implements Iterable.

But an additional issue is that you are trying to iterate using `LineObject` which will not work since your `ListStore` is declared using `String` i.e. `ListStore<String>` and not `ListStore<LineObject>`

Here is some sample code:

```
public void cycle(ListStore<String> line_data){

    List<String> lineListData = line_data.getAll();

    //for(LineObject line: lineListData){ <-- won't work since you are using Strings

    for(String line: lineListData){ // <-- this will work but probably not what you want
          //Other code goes here
    }

}
```

Looking back on your edits to your question you probably just want to use `LineObject`:

```
public void cycle(ListStore<LineObject> line_data){

    List<LineObject> lineListData = line_data.getAll();

    for(LineObject line: lineListData){
          //Other code goes here
    }

}
```